# Use delegate to show/hide a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have a `tableview` with three rows, In the second row there is UISwitch that when it's off, the third row should be hidden and when it's on, it would be shown.

I use delegate for that:
here is the protocol:

```
protocol ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate {
func toggle(isOn: Bool)
}
```

and here is the configuration of the delegate in `UITableViewCell`

```
@IBOutlet weak var deadlineSwitchState: UISwitch!

func configure(swicthIsOn: Bool, delegate: ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate) {
    deadlineSwitchState.isOn = swicthIsOn
    self.switchBtnDelegate = delegate
}

@IBAction func changeStateToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if deadlineSwitchState.isOn == true {
    switchBtnDelegate!.toggle(isOn:true)
    } else {
        switchBtnDelegate!.toggle(isOn:false)
    }
}

var switchBtnDelegate: ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate?
```

and here is some part of the codes in `UIViewController`

```
class AddListPopup: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate {

// Delegate

private var switchBtnIsOn = false

func toggle(isOn: Bool) {
    self.switchBtnIsOn = isOn
    NewListDetailsTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (taskCellArray.count - 1 ) + (switchBtnIsOn ? 1 : 0)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    indexPath.row == 1 {
    let switchCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switch cell", for: indexPath) as! NewListPopupViewCell

    switchCell.configure(swicthIsOn: switchBtnIsOn, delegate: self) //Set delegate here

    return switchCell
}
return UITableViewCell()
}
```

the problem is:

I will get two errors here:
first, if I unwrap `switchBtnDelegate` in `UITableViewCell` same as the code you see here, I got:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

this error appears here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var deadlineSwitchState: UISwitch!

@IBAction func changeStateToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
if deadlineSwitchState.isOn == true {
switchBtnDelegate!.toggle(isOn:true) //The error appears here
} else {
    switchBtnDelegate!.toggle(isOn:false)
}
}

var switchBtnDelegate: ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate?
```

and If i use ? to keep it optional:

```
@IBOutlet weak var deadlineSwitchState: UISwitch!

@IBAction func changeStateToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
if deadlineSwitchState.isOn == true {
switchBtnDelegate?.toggle(isOn:true) 
} else {
    switchBtnDelegate?.toggle(isOn:false)
}
}

var switchBtnDelegate: ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate?
```

I got this error:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {   Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

Could anyone help me to where the problem comes from?

Thank you so much

Comment: Where do you **set** the delegate? In `cellForRow`? Don't force unwrap delegate calls. By the way you can reduce the code in `changeStateToggle` to `@IBAction func changeStateToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) { switchBtnDelegate?.toggle(isOn: sender.isOn) }`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @vadian and sorry I forget to show all of the details, the first post is updated.  I set the delegate in 'cellForRowAt', but I still get the 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'. And thanks I will reduce the code how you guided me

Comment: Is the `IBOutlet` connected in the cell? Is the class of the custom cell set to `NewListPopupViewCell` in Interface Builder? Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information. And unrelated but dequeue **always all** cells. You are strongly discouraged from returning generic `UITableViewCell()`

Comment: Yes all IBOutlet is connected in the cell and set to NewListPopupViewCell

Comment: @vadian In the debug area it shows this error: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd3a4068800'

Comment: Aaah. Then check the `IBAction` in Interface Builder.

Comment: @vadian already gave you the answer: you hadn't set the `IBAction` properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)

The reason that your delegate is not being set *appears to be* that you are missing an `if` in your code on the first line of `tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt:IndexPath)`. It looks like that code in the block that you had intended to be an `if` statement is never running.

I would add an `if` on that first line and see if it is doing what you wanted.

Update: This would also explain the message `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd3a4068800'` in the console, because your method would always return a `UITableViewCell`, instead of a `NewListPopupViewCell`.

(2)

Crashing like this

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {   Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

usually happens to me when:
 1. I'm trying to load a Storyboard that is not part of the target, or
 2. I'm trying to use a segue that is not on the controller I'm messaging, or
 3. There are missing connections between the controller and other elements in the storyboard.

So, I would make sure that everything in your storyboard (or xib) has the appropriate connections, and try again.

(3)

Regarding the delegate ... You should make sure that your delegates are always declared using the `weak` keyword, and they are always treated as optional.

```
weak var delegate: ChangeStatusOFSwitchBtnDelegate?
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Mike, There is some problem with storyboard, because I tried many methods and it is needed to be cleaned up. Thank you Vadian for your help as well.